# VueJS components prop execution order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm using vuejs and vue-apollo in my project.

I have to components : `GroupList` and `GroupForm`

The thing is that I first arrive on the list, and then when I click on one of the groups, I arrive in the form view of that group.
To do that, I have a button that opens the form view by giving the `id` of that group :

```
openGroupFormView (group, index) {
  this.$router.push({ name: 'GroupFormView', params: { groupId: group.id } })
}
```

In the past, I used to pass the group object as paramater and it worked but I changed my mind and now I want to pass the `id` so that when the component `GroupForm` is opened, the graphql query to retrieve this group based on the `id` is executed. I want to do that in order to avoid apollo-cache inconsistencies in case where someone edited the same group in the meantime.

So in my `GroupForm` component I have :

> My prop :

```
props: {
  groupId: Number
}
```

> My component query :

```
apollo: {
  group: {
    query: GROUP_QUERY,
    variables () {
      return {
        id: this.groupId
      }
    },
    ..
}
```

> The associated query beneath that :

```
const GROUP_QUERY = gql`
  query ($id: ID) {
    group (id: $id) {
      id
      name
      usersCount
      userIds {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My problem is that in `data ()` of my component, I used to use the group that I passed through the props as an object. Now, I still want to do things on the group but the `apollo` part is executed after the `data ()` part so I have an undefined problem. How could I ensure that this problem doesn't occur ? I mean that apollo query is run first.

> My data() block :

```
data () {
  return {
    form: {
      name: this.group === undefined ? '' : this.group.name
    }
  }
},
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

> EDIT : A part of my template

```
  <b-form>
    <b-form-group label="Name">
      <b-form-input
        type="text"
        v-model="form.name"
        required
        :disabled="!editing"/>
    </b-form-group>
    <div v-if="editing" class="mb-3">
      <b-button @click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</b-button>
      <b-button @click="group === undefined ? createGroup() : updateGroup(group)" variant="success">Save</b-button>
    </div>
  </b-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Apollo but it looks like you should be able to initialize `name` to an empty string and then use the `result` hook to set it when the query completes.

Untested:

```js
apollo: {
  group: {
    ...
    result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
      this.form.name = data.name // something like this
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I tested it and it works.. But I have the feeling of doing some kind of a workaround... Furthermore, the `result` hook is crossed twice and I don't know why. The first time it is crossed, data is undefined. And then it's okay.

Comment: It seems that the fact that it is called twice is because I used the global option `fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'`. Using `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` solves this part of the problem. But I still have the feeling to use a workaround here.

Comment: It's clearly not a workaround since it only uses the hook as directed by the official [docs](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/api/smart-query.html). Perhaps there are multiple ways to do it, though there is no reason to think this is a problem.  If you want to edit your question to show your template and the way you use Apollo data in your template, maybe I can make a different suggestion. Maybe you don't need a name property at all.

Comment: I added a part of my template (the part with the form).

Comment: Again, I don't use Apollo but it seems you should be able to use `group.name` instead of `form.name` in the template.  If you must use `form` for other reasons (such as because you are going to submit it), there is no better suggestion, because you need a way to copy `group` into `form`, and there is no better place to do that than the `result` hook.

Comment: I do need the form for some reasons but that wasn't the problem ^^. Well I will adapt my code in order to use this result hook everywhere in my application in order to be able to apply this mechanism for every form view I have. Thanks dude this was helpful.